# Pulling info from an api url

Tags: python, json, urllib

I'm trying to pull the average of temperatures from this API from a bunch of different ZIP codes. I can currently do so by manually changing the ZIP code in the URL for the API, but I was hoping it to be able to loop through a list of ZIP codes or ask for input and use those zip codes.
However, I'm rather new and have no idea on how to add variables and stuff to a link, either that or I'm overcomplicating it. So basically I was searching for some methods to add a variable to the link or something to the same effect so I can change it whenever I want.

```
import urllib.request
import json

out = open("output.txt", "w")
link = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip={zip-code},us&appid={api-key}"
print(link)
x = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
url = x.read()

out.write(str(url, 'utf-8'))

returnJson = json.loads(url)
print('\n')
print(returnJson["main"]["temp"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import urllib.request
import json

zipCodes = ['123','231','121']

out = open("output.txt", "w")

for i in zipCodes:
   link = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=" + i + ",us&appid={api-key}"
   x = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
   url = x.read()
   out.write(str(url, 'utf-8'))
   returnJson = json.loads(url)
   print(returnJson["main"]["temp"])
   
out.close()
```

You can achieve what you want by looping through a list of zipcodes and creating a new URL from them.

Comment: So I really was just overthinking it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Made an edit to the code to match what you had originally. I hope this works. If it does, be  sure to mark it as correct. @FalseKing