# TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable when calc temp averages from json

Tags: python, json, api, average

I am trying to figure out how to average the temperatures from a json file and am having trouble with the conversion. It keeps throwing the error of: TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable when calc temp averages from json

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> import json
>>>
>>> zipcode_list = ["72714","71640","72454","71834","72223","72110"]
>>> for one_zipcode in zipcode_list:
...     link = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip="+one_zipcode+"&appid=e7c3fb6e681c8f7bb59af33f1dc8bbca"
...     f = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
...     data = f.read()
...     weather = json.loads(data)
...     n = (weather["name"])
...     x = (weather["main"]["temp"])
...     fh = (x-273.1)*9/5+32
...     total = round(fh, 2)
...     print (n, ":", total, "Farenheit")
...     avg = (x["main"]["temp"].mean())
...     print(avg)
...
Bella Vista : 11.93 Farenheit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in <module>
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Please reformat your code.

Comment: What's the trouble you're having in particular?

Comment: When I attempt to calculate the averages, it throws an error of TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: I attempted to calculate it with just the "x" but it does divides each city by 6 instead of adding them all together and then dividing. I am still playing around with it, attempting to figure it out but no luck so far.

Comment: I think I helped your classmate on this yesterday. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66180055/pulling-info-from-an-api-url/66180111#66180111

Comment: I looked at it, and am not seeing my error of adding the averages. I have been up for several hours working on this so it could just be my eyes. I am fully able to pull from the API and URL with great success, and even got it to print correctly, but am unable to get the averages of the temps

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback. This should also include one or more lines of code from your program.

Comment: Paste your json file. Most likely you are using wrong way to get the values of `n` or `x`.

Comment: Part of the json file reads

Comment: {"coord":{"lon":-92.7354,"lat":35.1692},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":268.68,"feels_like":262.6,"temp_min":268.15,"temp_max":269.15,"pressure":1024,"humidity":80},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":4.63,"deg":20},"clouds":{"all":90},"dt":1613209366,"sys":{"type":1,"id":3764,"country":"US","sunrise":1613221144,"sunset":1613260286},"timezone":-21600,"id":0,"name":"Morrilton","cod":200}

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to collect up all the values of `total` and find the mean?

```py
import statistics

temps=[]
for one_zipcode in zipcode_list:
    link = link = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip="+one_zipcode+"&appid=e7c3fb6e681c8f7bb59af33f1dc8bbca"
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
    data = f.read()
    weather = json.loads(data)
    n = weather["name"]
    x = weather["main"]["temp"]
    fh = (x - 273.1) * 9 / 5 + 32
    total = round(fh, 2)
    print(n, ":", total, "Farenheit")
    temps.append(total)
avg = statistics.mean(temps)
print(avg)
```

Comment: Oh wow, Thank you so much. I was way overthinking the problem. Did not even realize the append. Thanks so much!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You assign a float to `x` then later you try to subscript `x` which is why you are seeing the error message. See below.

```
x = (weather["main"]["temp"])
...
avg = (x["main"]["temp"].mean())
```